# Bootstrap panel opens then snaps shut

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap panel divs open when clicked but immediately snap shut (instead of toggling).

How I can keep them open until I click on them again?

```html
<div class="panel-group" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
            <center><a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">Show data assumptions</a></center>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Yearly property increase - 7%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Property rental yield - 8%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Initial discount on property - 20%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Mortgage deposit - 25%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Mortgage interest rate - 4.5%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Equities holding fees - 0.85%</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Yearly equities increase - 10.99%</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Live example: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/property-vs-shares/ (click on 'show data assumptions').

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a `panel`. It's been replaced with `card`. Otherwise, the code you've posted doesn't have a collapse issue: https://www.codeply.com/go/6OEVdLOaeB Please post the code to reproduce the collapse issue. Most likely there is other CSS effecting the collapse of the panel.

Comment: Thanks Zim, I agree however on my site it doesn't work. I just tried in a Bootrap 4 JSFiddle template and it worked fine. Very strange.

Comment: Remove any other (custom) css AND JavaScript and then start adding them one by one. That's how you troubleshoot to see what's doing the breaking. Simple.